# Is there a verb for identifying a married woman who is known by her maiden name?

Tags: single-word-requests

Whenever the maiden name is different from married name for women, is there a verb for identifying a married woman who is known by her maiden name?

Comment: What do you mean by maiden name?

Comment: What do you mean by "identifying"?

Comment: And I don't think you're really wanting a verb, are you?

Comment: @Noah Wherever the change of woman's name after her marriage is practiced, maiden name is the name of a woman before her marriage

Comment: You probably mean adjective since you want to describe an attribute of an object.

Comment: @Thale What do you mean by "a verb for identifying"? This would mean that you want to describe the action of identifying. Are you looking for an adjective to describe such a woman, or a noun by which to name her?

Comment: @nxx I want to express this line - she is "using her maiden name" as she is "a verb here". Adjectives and nouns are also welcome otherwise.

Comment: @Thale "She is a [something]" requires a noun. "She [somethings]" or "She [is somethinging]" would call for a verb.

Comment: @nxx I made a mistake. Thanks for the correction. But I suppose I have to settle with David M's answer - nee.

Comment: @Thale That's cool. It was just FYI :) You could always edit your question though if you want to get more answers (you can even un-accept an answer if that is your desire).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no common way to identify a woman who has maintained her maiden name.  (Or to identify a married woman who does not use the term Mrs., for that matter.  A woman who uses the term Dr. for example.)

The typically used method for identifying a woman as having a different name from her [maiden name](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maiden%20name) is:

[***Née***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nee)  -- It is the French feminine past participle of naître (to be born).

In other words: *Jane Jones née Smith* means *Jane Jones (who was born Jane Smith)*.

Compare this practice to women who hyphenate their names: Jane Smith-Jones.  Where again, Smith is her maiden name, and Jones is her married name.

Née *can* still be used to identify a woman who has kept her maiden name, as its meaning is still *born*.  And, I've seen this construction applied in the past.  But, it feels rather strange to see Jane Jones née Jones.  Most would assume that she married a man of the same name.

Comment: I think the question is about a married women who uses her maiden name as her last name even though she is still married. Née refers to her maiden name and does not indicate that the married women actually continues to use her maiden name as her last name.

Comment: @ram Née would actually still apply.  It would seem strange, but it just means born.  I guess I misinterpreted the question, but I've edited to answer that portion of it.

Comment: I understand and agree with your translation; my point is that the request is for a word that specifically indicates that the women *continues* to use her maiden name which I believe née does not. Consider Jane Jones who is married to Jim Jeffries; while most Jane's would go by Jane Jeffries this one goes by Jane Jones. Construct a sentence using née that conveys that Jane goes by Jones  ant not by Jeffries where the distinction is implied strictly by the word née. Notice that Jane Jones née Jane Jones does not convey the desired meaning.

Comment: @Ram I have actually seen that very construction.  But, I agree as to its strangeness.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't follow your reply to me - would you clarify for me? I certainly don't want to down vote if I'm wrong :|

Comment: @Ram Please read my revision.

Comment: just noticed that. I no longer disagree with your answer but I don't think it answers the question although clearly it does address it. Cheers.

Comment: @Ram I believe that no is sometimes an answer.  But, a no that explains the convention otherwise is better than a flat no.  But, I agree . . . It would be better were there a proper answer.